# Convert Multiple Frames of a Sprite to SVG

Tags: svg, flash

(For reference, was using question 6542614)

I used that, and the best I could do was convert the swf that had the sprite in it and multiple frames into a svg, which only shows the first frame (maybe?). How do I make it show each frame?

On a side note, some frames contain shapes and other sprites. Is there any way to get those as well or do I have to manually extract those and paste them together?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't the best option but you can try download and use **Texture Packer** and FlashUnpacker

Comment: I installed both, but when I insert a swf it says "Processing... trying to abort" Eh?